# Iterating through 2d tuples by index of nested tuple

Tags: python-2.7

What is a good pythonic way to rewrite the following? the idea is to be able to decide different actions for different indices of the nested lists.

Consider the nested lists can only be 2 dimensional, but both the top list and the nested can have any length.

```
resulttable = ''
list2d = [[1,2][3,4]]
for row in list2d:
    newrow=u'<tr>'
    for idx in range(len(row)):if idx=0 ....
        if idx==0:
            newrow=newrow+u'<td align="left">'+unicode(row[idx])+u'</td>'
        else:
            newrow=newrow+u'<td align="right">'+unicode(row[idx])+u'</td>'
    resulttable+=newrow + '</tr>'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to split your code into smaller testable functions. It can look something like this:

```
def _cell2td(idx, cell):
    if idx == 0:
        return u'<td align="left">' + unicode(cell) + u'</td>'
    return u'<td align="right">' + unicode(cell) + u'</td>'

def _row2tr(row):
    tds = [_cell2td(idx, cell) for idx, cell in enumerate(row)]
    row_repr = u'<tr>' + u''.join(tds) + u'</tr>'
    return row_repr

list2d = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
trs = map(_row2tr, list2d)
resulttable = ''.join(trs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably more fun to write than it is to read:

```
list2d = [[1,2],[3,4]]
resulttable= ""
for row in list2d:
    resulttable += "<tr>{}</tr>".format("".join([u'<td align="left">'+unicode(val)+u'</td>' if y == 0 else u'<td align="right">'+unicode(val)+u'</td>' for y, val in enumerate(row)]))
```

One line:

```
resulttable = "".join(["<tr>%s</tr>" % "".join([u'<td align="left">%s</td>' % unicode(val) if y == 0 else u'<td align="right">%s</td>' % unicode(val) for y, val in enumerate(row)]) for row in list2d])
```